# Tab Keydown event for HTML5 Date inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, input

I'm having a problem capturing Tab Keydown events on date inputs. Say I have a form with five inputs, the first and last of which are date inputs (the html here is for reference... I know it's missing ID, tabindex, etc.):

```
<form id="heyImAForm">
    <input type="date" id="in1" />
    <input type="text" id="notimportant2" />
    <input type="text" id="notimportant3" />
    <input type="text" id="notimportant4" />
    <input type="date" id="in5" />
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is call a method when the user Shift-Tabs out of the first input, and when the user Tabs out of the last input.

The problem is, I'd like to preserve the native Tab key behavior for date inputs, which is to move between days/months/years. So, something like this:

```
$('#in1').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 9 && e.shiftKey) {
        doAThing();
    }
});
$('#in5').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 9) {
        doADifferentThing();
    }
});
```

.... "works", but effectively kills that native Tab key behavior. So, long story short, is there a way to only trigger the Tab key event if the focus shifts away from the date input, as opposed to moving between day/month/year?

Comment: I worked very hard on this answer so please let me know how it goes and if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a few things I think the best solution would be what you see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D6umL/6/) but please read on to get a full understanding of what I am doing. We are setting the `focusout` when the user hits shift-tab on the first element or shift without tab on the second element. We must unbind this action if the user hit something else so we don't fire the action if they shift-tab but stay within the element then shift out of it. So try something like this:

```
$('#in1').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 9 && e.shiftKey) {
    $(document).mousedown(function(){
      $('#in1').unbind('focusout');
      $(document).unbind('mousedown');
    });
    $('#in1').focusout(function(){
      doAThing();
    });
  } else {
    $('#in1').unbind('focusout');
    $(document).unbind('mousedown');
  }
});
$('#in5').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 9 && !e.shiftKey) {
    $(document).mousedown(function(){
      $('#in5').unbind('focusout');
      $(document).unbind('mousedown');
    });
    $('#in5').focusout(function(){
      doADifferentThing();
    });
  } else {
    $('#in5').unbind('focusout');
    $(document).unbind('mousedown');
  }
});
```

You can see we are also setting `mousedown` of the entire document when the shift-tab(in1) or tab-without-shift(in5) is being hit. In the `mousedown` we are unbinding the `focusout` so if the focus leaves because of a mouse click we don't fire `doAThing()`. We also unbind `mousedown` on the document because you don't want it firing every time the user clicks after tabbing(in5) or shift-tabbing(in1) on those elements.

You may also be interested in seeing what I did on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D6umL/). This isn't the best solution because the setTimeout's can cause some problems and undesired effect in many cases.

Also, in your provided code the closing tag should be `</form>` not `</div>`.